# How to create an Eclipse plug-in for an SDK

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am trying to create an eclipse plug-in for an existing SDK. My main goal is to allow user to create a project that will automatically have the SDK jar file and will also load couple of examples. The main purpose is to free the user from the hassle of adding jar file and looking up the examples.

I am fairly new to this area of development. I have never created a plugin and was wondering if there are any specific tutorials or development guide for creating such a plugin.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what your requirements are, what the SDK are, what type of users you developing for. But the simplest solution would be to create a set of Eclipseprojects with a proper setup. Then your user would just import them and continue to build from them.

A more elaborate solution would be a new project wizard. So when the user goes to file -> new project, they will find a specific wizard this type of development. If this is what you are looking for, then [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseWizards/article.html) will offer a good starting point.